# usbmon: data rate analysis

Tags: usb, rate

I wrote a small program to evaluate the textual interface of the kernel module usbmon. It is supposed to calculate the data rate towards or from a single bus device. Therefore I only look at callback (C) and Bulk output (Bo) events and add up the data length fields. Yet, when copying 100 MB of zeros with dd to a USB storage device, I get an overhead of roughly 1.3 % (stable), when counting all bytes together. As soon as the device is mounted there are events I can see via usbmon also when no file copying is ongoing.

Does somebody have an explanation for this overhead? Is it possible to get rid of it?